# Unable to remove EventListener

Tags: typescript, pointerlock

I have a TypeScript class which looks something like this:

```
class MyClass {

    let canvas: any;

    constructor(canvas: any) {

        this.canvas = canvas;

        this.canvas.requestPointerLock = this.canvas.requestPointerLock;
        document.exitPointerLock = document.exitPointerLock;

        this.canvas.onclick = this._mouseClickHandler.bind(this);
        document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', this._togglePointerLock.bind(this), false);
    }

    private _mouseClickHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.canvas.requestPointerLock();
    }

    private _togglePointerLock() {
        if (document.pointerLockElement === this.canvas) {
            console.info('Locked mouse pointer to canvas.');
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', this._handleMouseMovement.bind(this), false);
        } else {
            console.info('Unlocked mouse pointer from canvas.');
            // THIS DOES NOT WORK
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this._handleMouseMovement.bind(this), false);
        }
    }

    private _handleMouseMovement(event: MouseEvent) {
        console.log('Mouse moved to: ', event.movementX, event.movementY);
    }
}
```

Basically the code is supposed to register the `_handleMouseMovement` event listener after the mouse has been locked to the canvas and and remove it once the lock has been removed.

The locking does work. It activates the position logging in `_handleMouseMovement` but once I remove the lock via `ESC` I do get the message `Unlocked mouse pointer from canvas.` So `_handleMouseMovement` is not removed and position logging continues.

I think that I did pay attention to not register anonymous functions, which might be the cause for a problem like this. So I wonder what else might be causing this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.bind` creates a *new* function. So your addition and removal are not for the same function.

## Fix

[Don't use `.bind`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/bind.html) and instead use arrow functions:

```
private _handleMouseMovement = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    console.log('Mouse moved to: ', event.movementX, event.movementY);
}
```